# Questions about central polygonal numbers $1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46,\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Formula for [Central polygonal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence) is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1$, if $n=1$ or $n$ is prime, we get the new sequence $A$:

> 2, 4, 7, 16, 29, 67, 92, 154, 191, ...

It seems that all primes either is terms of $A$ or can be expressed by adding and subtracting distinct terms of $A$? Such as:
$$
\begin{align*} 
&2 \\
&3=7-4 \\
&5=7-2  \\
&\cdots \\
&17=16+7-2-4\\
&\cdots 
\end{align*}
$$
How to prove this?

Comment: I'm sure it's true that every integer can be expressed by adding and subtracting terms of $A$. The circle method can surely show that there exists an integer $s$ such that every sufficiently large number can be written as the sum of $s$ terms of $A$ (and the asymptotic formula for the number of such representations can be used to ensure that these $s$ terms can be chosen to be distinct). Then for any target integer $p$, find such a representation for a large $s$ and $s+p$ and subtract them.

Comment: @GregMartin If it's true, are there other seqs have less terms than $A$ that also can do the same?

Comment: $2,5,18,38,82,164,\dots$; you get 2, $3=5-2$, 5, $7=2+5$, $11=18-5-2$, $13=38-18-5-2$, $17=82-38-18-5-2$, $19=164-82-38-18-5-2$, and so on.

Comment: @miket: certainly - the sequence of $k$th powers for any $k$, for example.